# What is the mechanism used for having iOS devices communicate with each other?

Tags: ios

Is is possible to have two iOS devices talk to each other without having a wireless network present?

If a network is required, can they communicate with each other without having a third device (a web server or something similar) to host the communication?

Comment: You can use Bluetooth with GameKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can use Bluetooth or ad-hoc wireless network to the same effect. Apple in fact provides a framework designed to enable this: Game Kit.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1) on the subject for more information.

Comment: I can use Wifi for a larger range than bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, Wi-fi is supported (though it's transparent to you). I'm not sure off the top of my head whether it requires an existing network, or whether GK will actually create an ad-hoc network for you.

All you do is ask Game Kit to search for nearby peers (nearby, online or both: you can choose), and it will reach out using the available means to look for other instances of your application doing the same. You don't have to worry about whether it's using Bluetooth, Wi-fi, or some future technology that doesn't exist yet.