# How do I create a user login, password and ability to exchange messages between users in my iphone app

Tags: ios

How do I create unique user login, password and ability to exchange messages between users in my iphone app without using a server. Is it even possible?

Comment: Your questions lacks details ... Do you want to communicate over the internet or just a local network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate between iOS devices using bluetooth or WiFi using gamekit/GKSessions. Short communications or messaging may work just fine.

But username password without server sounds tricky. I do not know if there is any existing framework for this. However, if you are to maintain a network over a predetermined number of devices, you may create an user and share it over bluetooth. That will be a non-standard approach but might work.

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559787/what-is-the-mechanism-used-for-having-ios-devices-communicate-with-each-other

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's what I suspected ...and now I have to learn a whole bunch more stuff! lol